# How do you import a JSON model to Three.js...?

Tags: json, model, import, three.js

I was looking at an older question that had this a code that was fixed to this:

but it won't work for some reason. Are there any JSON files available that work for sure that I could test with?

I tried a json of a ship I exported using the three.js editor (ship.js) and it just doesnt seem to display anything- in fact, it won't "hit" the alert I have set, indicating an issue with the load of the json file, perhaps?

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, loader;

init();
animate();

function init() {

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 1000;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "ship.js", function( geometry ) {

    //var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5,10,5);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.position.x = 0;
scene.add( mesh );
            alert("hit");

} );



var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

mesh.rotation.x += 0.05;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.05;

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the .js files inside `examples/obj` here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip

Comment: I tried Bird.js and it didn't work-

Comment: Bird.js is a bit special... Try `examples/obj/leeperrysmith/LeePerrySmith.js`.

Comment: IT WORKED!! So it was just the JSON files themselves... hmm

Comment: Ok, so I notice when I try to export a scene in the editor, it puts out a JSON file with type "object" and it won't work, but when I export a single geometry, the type becomes "geometry" and it works with the three.js file- is the problem because it's reading an exported scene as an object rather than a geometry then? If so, how would I go about adding an "object" to the scene without a mesh?